# passing list to template in bottle

Tags: python, list, wsgi, template-engine, bottle

I have a list consist of post information as list of tuples (list consist of tuples) 
but I faced the problem of how to pass it to template in bottle i've tried a lot,, and checked most of the Questions in stackoverflow and I could't find a good and clear question.

Here's what I have tried:

```
@route('/v/:name')
def page_viwer(name):
    id=db.searchU('user', name)
    result=db.searchU_forG(id[0][0])
    if len(result)>0:#if we got posts 
        return template('v',post=result)
```

And here is `v.tpl`

```
<html>
%for post in res:
    %for id, title, dec, pic,not_needed in post:
        <h3>{{id}}</h3>
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
        <h3>{{dec}}</h3>
        <h3>{{pic}}</h3>
        <br/>
%end
</html>
```

When I tried this, I got Error 500 ... And when I checked the logs this is the reason:

`%for id, title, dec, pic in post:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: It seems that it lacks of another `%end` in `v.tpl`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've dug around and found this works fine and great ..

```
<html>

<table>
  %for item in res:
    title:{{item[1]}}
    <br/>
    Decription:{{item[2]}}
    <br/>
    Picture:{{item[3]}}
    <br/>
    posted by:{{item[4]}}
    <br/>
    <br/>
  %end
</table>

</html>
```